# Android global layout listener called repeatedly in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Add global layout listener gets called even if there is no listener attached, It gets in a loop in this situation, how can I edit attributes without firing global layout listener in a loop ? thank you

```
final View getDecorView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
            getDecorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
                        getDecorView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    } else {
                        getDecorView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    }

                    final TextView textView3 = (TextView) decorView.findViewById(2131558456);
                    if (textView3 != null) {
                                textView3.setText("updated");                      textView3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#444444"));
                    }

                    getDecorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                }
            });
```

Comment: Change `getDecorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);` to `getDecorView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);` inside your `onGlobalLayout()`

Comment: @NicolasSimon is right, you're re-attaching a `GlobalLayoutListener` at the end of each call, which is why it is called repeatedly. Remove that line.

Comment: @roarster That is what I want to do actually, I want it to be fired except setting text, that is why I attach listener after removing, how can I achieve this ? thank you.

Answer (score 6):

This sort of solves your problem:

```
final View decorView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
final TextView textView3 = (TextView) decorView.findViewById(2131558456);
decorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
            decorView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
            decorView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }


        if (textView3 != null && !textView3.getText().equals("updated")) {
            textView3.setText("updated");
            textView3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#444444"));
        }

        decorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

    }
});
```

I'm assuming that `textview3` doesn't originally have text equal to "updated", so when you set its text to "updated", it acts as a sort of flag, so that you don't set it again in the future. You could also do the following, which IMHO is a bit cleaner because you have an actual boolean flag representing whether you should update the `TextView` or not.

```
final View decorView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
final TextView textView3 = (TextView) decorView.findViewById(2131558456);
decorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    boolean updateTextview = true;

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
            decorView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
            decorView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }


        if (textView3 != null && updateTextview) {
            updateTextview = false;
            textView3.setText("updated");
            textView3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#444444"));
        }

        decorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

    }
});
```

Both solutions should work, because they stop the constant updating of `textview3`, which leads to another layout pass which leads to the updating of `textview3` which leads to another layout pass which leads... on and on.

Comment: I have lots of views to update in this point, so checking with ifs would be a big problem for me, why its gets fired even there is no listener when setting but adding it later, do you have any idea ? thank you :)

Comment: `getDecorView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getDecorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
                    }
                });` This one worked, why do you think this one worked ? thank you

Comment: ah, I'd completely forgotten about `View#post()`! What it does is adds the `Runnable` to the UI message queue, which is run on the next iteration. So you add the `Runnable`, then Android decides to update the `TextViews`, and consequently triggers any messages on the UI thread to run, so your `Runnable` is run. There are some good explanations of SO, but you might find it works sometimes, and doesn't work other times. You could experiment with `View#postDelayed()` but I think you should be good with what you have :)

Answer (score 1):

This one solved the problem

```
final ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listener = this;

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
                    getDecorView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    getDecorView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }

                final TextView textView3 = (TextView) decorView.findViewById(2131558456);
                if (textView3 != null) {
                    textView3.setText("fert");
                    textView3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#444444"));
                }

                getDecorView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getDecorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
                    }
                });
```